# Default FirebaseApp is not initialized , Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Tags: firebase, illegalstateexception

> FATAL EXCEPTION java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp
> is not initialized Make sure to call
> FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

After upgrading all the dependencies and initialized FirebaseApp

still application keeps stopping

Comment: Show us the code you're using and Firebase dependencies,

Comment: getting error-Firebase Messaging
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("notification");

Comment: implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.1'